# resource leak : fExclfile

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, static-code-analysis, cppcheck, resource-leak

While checking my code in Cppcheck, I am getting the error "Resource leak: fExclfile". My program is not giving any compile error or crash. Please help me on this issue.

```
FILE           *fExclfile = NULL;
FILE           *fExclBadfile = NULL;
if (ExclBadfile != NULL) {
    fExclBadfile = fopen(ExclBadfile, "a");
    if (fExclBadfile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s Can't open the exclusion bad file \"%s\". Check permissions.\n", t_stamp(), ExclBadfile);
        fflush(stderr);
        return 0;   // <- getting resource leak -> 
    };
};
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a resource leak for fExclBadfile, which you aren't closing when you return?  You aren't using fExclfile, so a resource leak on that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: what's `ExclBadfile` and why are you allocating it on the heap? If it's a resource on the heap and you don't destroy it when you exit, then that's a potential memory leak

Comment: Sorry @Matt Jordan.  It is "Resource leak: fExclBadfile".

Comment: @Matt Jordan:  if i add 'fclose(ExlBadfile);  before return 0, will it solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, I would think fclose(fExclBadfile) would solve the problem, since that cleans up the resources that are allocated by fopen.

Answer (score 1):

just ensure that you close all open file handles before the program exits and `ExclBdfile` needs to be deallocated too if it's created on the heap